# Rendering in JUNG

Tags: java, graph, jung

I've to display a graph like a tree level in hierarchy so I use the TreeLayout included in Jung (it's a general tree). I have based my code in MinimumSpanningTreeDemo.java, and works fine for simple cases, but when are more complex like the picture, I obtain something like the right side instead of something like the left side (which I intended to).

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM28s.png)
[image]
The layout that I used it's follows:

```
Graph<String,String> graph,graphcopy;
Forest<String,String> tree;
Layout<String,String> layout;
AbstractLayout layout2; 

    MinimumSpanningForest2<String,String> prim = 
        new MinimumSpanningForest2<String,String>(graph,
            new DelegateForest<String,String>(), DelegateTree.<String,String>getFactory(),
            new ConstantTransformer(1.0));

    tree = prim.getForest();
    collapser = new GraphCollapser(graph);

    layout = new TreeLayout<String,String>(tree,100,100);
    layout2 = new StaticLayout<String,String>(graph, layout);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to add that my problem is that this is a directed graph that I want to display like a tree, but when there are two or more roots, the result is not that I expected.
Thanks!

Comment: In what way is the result not what you expected?  Please be specific.